# Emgu.CV.MatInvoke' threw an exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, emgucv

DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'cvextern': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DetectFacesAndBlur(string imagePath)
    {
       var imageString= imagePath.Split(',')[1];
        string base64String = imageString;
        Mat image = new Mat();
        // Convert the base64 string to a byte array
        byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);

    
   CvInvoke.Imdecode(imageBytes, ImreadModes.Color, image);

        // Load a pre-trained face recognition model
        EigenFaceRecognizer recognizer = new EigenFaceRecognizer();
        recognizer.Read("face_recognition_model.xml");

        // Detect faces in the image
        Emgu.CV.CascadeClassifier faceCascade = new CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");
        Rectangle[] faces = faceCascade.DetectMultiScale(image, 1.1, 3,Size.Empty);

       
        bool isFaceDetected = faces.Length > 0;
        bool isBlurred = 22 > 100;
        // Return the result
        return Json(new { IsBlurred = isBlurred, IsFaceDetected = isFaceDetected });
    }
```